# Visual studio formatting of selection in CSS editor not working

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-formatting

Some strange issue appeared while working in Visual Studio 2010.
 Formatting for whole `CSS` file works fine `CTRL+K,CTRL+D`, but trying to format code inside of selection `CTRL+K,CTRL+F` shows an error:

```
 The key combination (CTRL+K, CTRL+F) is bound to command (Format Selection) which is not currently available.
```

Does anybody know what causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

When trying the second command, were you still formatting CSS or a different file type (.cs)?

Code which requires compiling can't be edited whilst running (debugging). HTML, CSS and Javascript can be edited whilst the code is currently running.

Not sure if that is the cause of your issue but that is how I can reproduce it.

Comment: I was editing CSS file. But editing of whole file was ok, the problem is only with formatting of section.